# Problems when setting up Frank for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cucumber, frank

I have a problem with setting up Frank in my iOS project.
I am following the instructions and executing in the console:

```
sudo gem install frank-cucumber -V
```

What I get is:

```
 ERROR:  Error installing frank-cucumber:
         activesupport requires i18n (= 0.6.1, runtime)
```

I have no idea what may be wrong. I checked the gems using:

```
gem list --local
```

and got:

```
i18n (0.6.4)
```

Do you know what may be wrong?
Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly the issue was solved by installing Rails.

```
gem install rails
```

It might be that it updated gems that frank needed. Maybe the activesupport as tapi suggested but I can't say it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a version mismatch between what `activesupport` requires and what you have installed.

I would try a `gem update` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the required version:

```
gem install i18n -v 0.6.1
```

If you still have problems, uninstall your previous version, by doing:

```
gem uninstall i18n -v 0.6.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did that and it didn't help.

Comment: What do you now see when you try "gem list"? Does it still give you 0.6.4?

Comment: It gives me i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1). But as I wrote in my answer the problem has been already solved.

Answer (score 1):

for me I had two versions of ruby on my machine, `1.8.7` and `1.9.3`.. and my default was `1.8.7` (don't ask why).. So I simply switched to ruby `1.9.3` and that problem disappeared

check which ruby version:

```
ruby -v
```

if it's not 1.9.3 switch to it

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

if you don't have 1.9.3 installed install it

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

for the future, I recommend setting 1.9.3 as default:

```
rvm --default 1.9.3
```

Comment: Helped me out in combination with this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/